# Call a Function although the form is Minimized or Unselected on KeyDown in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, function, keydown, topmost, minimized

Well I have this code:

```
Public Sub FuncKeysModule(ByVal value As Keys)
    'Check what function key is in a pressed state, and then perform the corresponding action.
    Select Case value
        Case Keys.F8
            spam.Enabled = True
            TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0
            state = "Activo"
        Case Keys.F9
            spam.Enabled = False
            TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1
            state = "Parado"
    End Select
End Sub

    Private Sub frmMain_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.F1 Or Keys.F2 Or Keys.F3 Or Keys.F4 Or Keys.F5 Or Keys.F6 Or Keys.F7 Or Keys.F8 Or Keys.F9 Or Keys.F10 Or Keys.F11 Or Keys.F12 Then
        FuncKeysModule(e.KeyValue)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

When I press F8 or F9 the Form call the function that you can see. But I have a dude, how can I do call it if the Form is Minimized or Unselected (if I have TopMost on True)?

Thanks. ;)

---

I have this code:

http://pastebin.com/Vr8UjVnF

But everytime that I run my project an Excepcion occur, **Could not set keyboard hook**

What can I do? :S

Comment: The article below should answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216222/vb-net-detecting-keypress-while-minimized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's posible, you have tu uncheck the "Enable Visual Studio hosting process" on the Properties -> Debug table of the project, and use this code:

http://pastebin.com/Vr8UjVnF

It's works :)