# C# - Check if specific key is pressed

Tags: c#, keyboard, key

I'm trying to check if a key is pressed, but I get these Error Message:

> Error  1   The name 'Keyboard' does not exist in the current context
>
> Error  2   The name 'Key' does not exist in the current context

Can you tell me how to fix it?

```
public void Main() 
{
    while(true) 
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Key.A)) 
        {
            //...
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a windows form that is running?

Comment: @DROP table users No, does it only work with a Windows Form?
The program should run in the background and recognize if i press a specific key

Comment: Sounds like your looking for keylogging functionality. An open source example in C# can be found here if you are wanting to learn: http://cskeylogger.codeplex.com/

Comment: He's looking for a a global hotkey, not a keylogger.

Comment: Why your Main method is not static?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to create a global hotkey in the system and your application should respond when it is pressed.

You will need two Win32 API functions [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [UnregisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Looking at your `using System.Windows.Input`, it seems like you are trying to do this with WPF, which is possible.

Let's start with your fairly basic P/Invokes:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr windowHandle, int hotkeyId, uint modifierKeys, uint virtualKey);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr windowHandle, int hotkeyId);
}
```

Now, when you register your `Window`, what happens is that a [WM_HOTKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message is sent to your application's message pump. However, WPF abstracts this message pump away from you, so you'll need to add a `HwndSourceHook` to tap into it.

How do we do all this? Let's start by initializing our `HwndSourceHook` delegate. Add this snippet to your `MainWindow`:

```
    using System.Windows.Interop;

    static readonly int MyHotKeyId = 0x3000;
    static readonly int WM_HOTKEY = 0x312;

    void InitializeHook()
    {
        var windowHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
        var windowSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowHelper.Handle);

        windowSource.AddHook(MessagePumpHook);
    }

    IntPtr MessagePumpHook(IntPtr handle, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == WM_HOTKEY)
        {
            if ((int)wParam == MyHotKeyId)
            {
                // The hotkey has been pressed, do something!

                handled = true;
            }
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

Alright, so now we have everything in place to respond to the `WM_HOTKEY` message. However, we need to register our hotkey still! Let's add another couple initialization methods:

```
    void InitializeHotKey()
    {
        var windowHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);

        // You can specify modifiers such as SHIFT, ALT, CONTROL, and WIN.
        // Remember to use the bit-wise OR operator (|) to join multiple modifiers together.
        uint modifiers = (uint)ModifierKeys.None;

        // We need to convert the WPF Key enumeration into a virtual key for the Win32 API!
        uint virtualKey = (uint)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(Key.A);

        NativeMethods.RegisterHotKey(windowHelper.Handle, MyHotKeyId, modifiers, virtualKey);
    }

    void UninitializeHotKey()
    {
        var windowHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
        NativeMethods.UnregisterHotKey(windowHelper.Handle, MyHotKeyId);
    }
```

Alright! Where do we put these? **Do not put them in the constructor!** Why? Because the `Handle` will be `0` and invalid! Put them here (in `MainWindow`):

```
    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        InitializeHook();
        InitializeHotKey();
    }
```

You can register multiple hotkeys, un-register and re-register new ones.. it's up to you. Just remember that *each* hotkey **must have a unique ID** registered to it. It only makes sense, as your message pump hook has to know *which* hotkey caused the `WM_HOTKEY` message!

It's also good practice to unregister all hotkeys when your application closes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a keyboard hook.  Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx) out, from [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5065906/1483002):

> Global keyboard hooks are not the right solution if you only want a
>   few global hotkeys. A high level keyboard hook means that your dll
>   will be injected into other applications, and shouldn't be done at all
>   in managed code. A low level keyboard hook is a bit better, since it
>   processes the keyboard events in your own application. Still it
>   requires that every keyboard event is handled by your thread.
>
> The windows API function RegisterHotKey is much better suited for
>   that.
>
> But using a smple F-Key as global hotkey is problematic since it might
>   collide with a local hotkey of the application that has focus. So you
>   should make global hotkeys configurable, so the user can avoid
>   collisions with his commonly used applications.

Answer (score 0):

The type of application is not clear. If you have a console application, not a Windows form one, you can try this:

```
while (true)
  if (Console.KeyAvailable) 
    if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.A)
    { 
      // Do something
    }
```

and read this if you want to have a global hotkey in a windows forms app: http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this in a windows forms application, maybe you can add these codes into the Form's KeyDown event(or which key event you need to use):

```
switch (e.KeyData)
{
    //Detects that you pressed the Up Arrow Key, which key do you need, just 
    //write it here.
    case Keys.Up: 
    //enter code here`
    break;
}
```

Comment: This is good for a Windows Form application, unfortunately the OP stated in the comments that is not what this is.  It appears that they're writing a program to see if a key is pressed in Windows itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `PresentationCore.dll` and `WindowsBase` to references and add to the header of the method `[STAThread]`