# Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A) returns false

Tags: c#, keyboard, xna

I am using `xna.framework` and there is a problem whit this

```
while (true)
        {
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something");
            }
        }
```

the if statement returns false whatever i do. I've seen another posts here about this problem, but there is no answer that helps me. Any ideas ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804234/c-sharp-check-if-specific-key-is-pressed

Comment: You should not use XNA do get the input in a console window. There are native functions to do that (see the link posted above). If you want to try out the basics of xna, use the blank template instead, because it comes with an update function so you don't have to do stuff like while(true). I am not sure, but I guess that would already solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include the `GetState()` method, also when getting the keycode for the A key you use `keys` rather than just `key`. Your new code would just be

```
while (true)
{
     if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A))
     {
           Console.WriteLine("Something");
     }
}
```

Comment: there is no method IsKeyDown on the keyboard class